# How do I pass SELECT PHP to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, select

I am new to PHP. Please advise me on how to use PHP in Javascript. My 1st Code sys_out_currency to put in the second code USD: 0.2493,

1st Code

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sys_currency_buy");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
?> 
<p><?php echo $row['sys_out_currency']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['sys_in_currency']; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

2nd Code

```
<script>
var MYRrates = {
USD: 0.2493, 
SGD: 0.3355, 
GBP: 0.1908, 
EUR: 0.2247, 
AUD: 0.3663, 
NZD: 0.3802, 
CAD: 0.3257, 
CHF: 0.2421, 
HKD: 1.94, 
CNY: 1.72, 
NT: 7.54, 
THB: 7.57,   
PHP: 13.33, 
INR: 18.34, 
SAR: 0.94, 
JPY: 273.9,   
KRW: 295.8, 
VND: 5700, 
IDR: 3400,     
};
```

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how you can use PHP inside javascript :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function test() {
        alert("<?php echo "Testing"; ?>");
    }
    test();// to call the function
</script>
```